# How to change properties of 1 segment in a segmented cell?

Tags: macos, cocoa, segmentedcontrol

How to change properties of 1 segment in a segmented cell? I can't find it.
This is what i've tried:

- Google
- Some experimenting: `_segmentedcell.SelectedSegment` (does not work)

Here is my AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSSegmentedCell *BackForward;
@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *WebBrowser;
- (IBAction)BackForwardAction:(id)sender;

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

And here is my AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (IBAction)BackForwardAction:(id)sender {
    if (_BackForward.selectedSegment == 0) {
        _WebBrowser.goBack;
        if (_WebBrowser.canGoBack == false) {
            //here it does need to disable segment 0
        }
    } else if (_BackForward.selectedSegment == 1) {
        _WebBrowser.goForward;
        if (_WebBrowser.canGoForward == false) {
            // here it does neet to disable segment 1
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how Google didn't lead you to [the class reference for `NSSegmentedControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSSegmentedControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but:

```
[_BackForward setEnabled:NO forSegment:0];
```